# Why can't I move an image with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.nav {
  height: 500px;
}

.navphoto {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="images/navphoto.jpg">
</div>
```

As the title says: why can't I move an image but when I put flex code into a .nav it's working.

Comment: Makes no sense to set an image as flex. Also, define *"move"*. Edit and improve

Comment: Question seems clear to me. Let me know if my explanation needs any additional details.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems:

- Your outer div is not a flex container
- `justify-content` is a property for a flex container

```css
.nav {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navphoto {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="images/navphoto.jpg">
</div>
```

Basically, trying to set the image itself as a flex-container doesn't do what you want because the image is not a child of itself. It's the entire element. You need some kind of flex container to layout within.

Comment: but how do I move only an image? Because if I have a text in a div and I apply flex, it moves everything: text and image.

Comment: Now I don't know what you're asking. If there's more context to your question, you need to include it or create a new one. We're not mind-readers.

Comment: Let's say I have a <p> random textttt </p> along with this image navphoto.jpg in my .nav div. How do I move those elements seperately with flexbox? Or do flexbox connect all the elements and I have to move all of them along?

Comment: Please update your question to be more accurate to what your situation is and desired outcomes. I'll update the answer appropriately. I don't want to make this answer inaccurate with respect to the actual question being asked, so the next person that finds this question can also be helped by it.

Answer (score 0):

From [CSS Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

> The `Flexbox` Layout (Flexible Box) module aims at providing a more efficient way to layout, align and distribute space among items in a **container**, even when their size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word “flex”).

Key word - **container**

It doesn't make much logical sense to `flex` the `img` element because it is not a container, it's a flex-item. If you had a different subset that contained the `img` and the `text` then it would make sense to `flex` it.

Please see the notes in the CSS below:

```css
/* nav would be the main container to position content with justify-content */

nav {
  border: dotted black 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content justify's content (blue container) on the x-axis */
  /*justify-content: center;*/ /* centered */
  /*justify-content: flex-start;/* /* start */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* end */
}

.nav {
  border: dotted blue 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  /*margin: auto;*/ /* will automatically center blue container despite what `justify-content` is defined as because width: 100%; is not defined and because the parent is flexed*/
  /* this is now another container because it has the img and p nested, you would use flex to get the items to align in a row if flex-direction: column; wasn't defined. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  /* you'll notice if you uncomment those flex properties justify-content doesn't do anything. why? because you can see by the borders there is no where for the content to justify. The p with the pink border is spanning 100% of the container, so you would have to use text-align: center; if you had width: fit-content; on p then you would use `align-items: center;` or `margin: auto; on p. Both do the same. */
  text-align: center;
}

.navphoto {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid orange 5px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  border: solid hotpink 2px;
  /*width: fit-content;*/
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav">
    <img class="navphoto" src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are applying `display: flex;` on `.navphoto`, apply it on `.nav`. Look at the following code

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 500px;
}

.navphoto {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img class="navphoto" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653629154351-3072ee211a9b">
</div>
```